# Java return value

Tags: java, return-value

I'm C programmer. I'd like the function `main` return a value but apparently main is alway void. Is it true in Java?

Comment: to it's maker. But with java being platform atheist...

Answer (score 17):

Main always returns void in Java.  If you want your program to return an error value use `System.exit()`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in Java main is always `public static void main(String[] args)`.  Why would you want it to return a value anyways?  It would just be returning to the enclosing `java.exe` process and not to the OS, which isn't very useful.

To exit and return a code to the OS, use `System.exit(int code)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.lang.System.exit(int status)` to return a non-zero status code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for `System.exit(int retValue)`

Answer (score 0):

yes , its true , you should call the function from the main with the class object .. or declare the function as static and call from main to do the work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The "main" function is the start of execution for your program, it's a "special" function which serves as the entry point to the application - you are not supposed to call it from other code and it does not return a value